# removing rows based on conditions in R

Tags: r, dataframe, filter

For my research, I have to remove certain trials to limit contamination in the data. Here are the rules:

Remove the first trial.

1. For RT calculation, remove error trials (trials with 0, trials with 1 are corrects trials) and trials following an error. Say, we have 20 trials and 3 errors, we have to remove 6 trials from the final data, i.e., mean RT will be calculated from 14 trials. If the errors are in a row, say 3 errors in a row, RT will be calculated based on 17 trials.
2. For error rate calculation, remove trials following an error. Say, we have 20 trials and 3 errors, we have to remove 3 trials following errors from the final data, i.e., error rate will be calculated by 3/17. If the errors are in a row, say 3 errors in a row, only the first error retains and the next two errors are excluded, so the error rate will be calculated by 1/18.

I am new to R. I hope someone can help me with the script. Thanx in advance

```
trial_no  correct
1   1
2   1
3   1
4   1
5   1
6   1
7   1
8   1
9   1
10  1
11  1
14  0
15  1
16  1
17  1  
18  1
19  0
20  1
21  1
22  1
23  0
24  0
25  1
26  1
27  1
28  1
29  1
30  1
31  1
32  0
33  0
34  1
35  1
36  1
37  1
38  1
39  0
40  1
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your correctly the two rules work as follows:

1. A trial is excluded from RT calculation if this trial *or* the preceding trial has `correct==0`.
2. A trial is excluded from RT calculation if the preceding trial has `correct==0`. (Changed this according to comments!)

If this is how you want things done, consider the two methods below.

Reproducing your example data:

```
df <- data.frame(trial_no = 1:40,
                 correct = rep(1, 40))
df$correct[c(13, 19, 23, 24, 32, 33, 39)] <- 0
```

Solution using base R only:

```
# usage for RT
df$use_rt <- df$correct==1
df$use_rt[2:nrow(df)][df$correct[-nrow(df)]==0] <- FALSE

# usage for error rate
df$use_er <- TRUE
df$use_er[2:nrow(df)] <- df$correct[-nrow(df)]==1

# calculate error rate
1 - mean(df$correct[df$use_er])
```

Solution using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

# usage for RT and error rate
df <- df %>%
  mutate(use_rt = correct==1 & lag(correct)==1,
         use_er = lag(correct)==1)
df$use_rt[1] <- df$correct[1]==1 # (without this you will have an NA-value in the first row)

# calculate error rate
df %>%
  filter(use_er) %>%
  summarize(error_rate = 1 - mean(correct))
```

The error rate is 0.1315789 (5 / 38).

For calculating reaction times you can now filter by `use_rt`, i.e. `df[df$use_rt,]`.

`df` resulting from either method:

```
trial_no correct use_rt use_er
1        1       TRUE   TRUE
2        1       TRUE   TRUE
3        1       TRUE   TRUE
4        1       TRUE   TRUE
5        1       TRUE   TRUE
6        1       TRUE   TRUE
7        1       TRUE   TRUE
8        1       TRUE   TRUE
9        1       TRUE   TRUE
10       1       TRUE   TRUE
11       1       TRUE   TRUE
12       1       TRUE   TRUE
13       0      FALSE   TRUE
14       1      FALSE   TRUE
15       1       TRUE   TRUE
16       1       TRUE   TRUE
17       1       TRUE   TRUE
18       1       TRUE   TRUE
19       0      FALSE   TRUE
20       1      FALSE   TRUE
21       1       TRUE   TRUE
22       1       TRUE   TRUE
23       0      FALSE   TRUE
24       0      FALSE  FALSE
25       1      FALSE   TRUE
26       1       TRUE   TRUE
27       1       TRUE   TRUE
28       1       TRUE   TRUE
29       1       TRUE   TRUE
30       1       TRUE   TRUE
31       1       TRUE   TRUE
32       0      FALSE   TRUE
33       0      FALSE  FALSE
34       1      FALSE   TRUE
35       1       TRUE   TRUE
36       1       TRUE   TRUE
37       1       TRUE   TRUE
38       1       TRUE   TRUE
39       0      FALSE   TRUE
40       1      FALSE   TRUE
```

Comment: Thank you for the above solution. It worked with my data. In case of error rate, I would like to clear the part. A trial is excluded from error rate calculation, when the preceeding trial has correct == 0. Also, if two consecutive trials have correct == 0, then the 1st trial remains and the 2nd correct == 0 and the trial succeeding it has to be excluded.
I hope this is clear.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the difference between what I did (with `use_er`) and what you write.

Comment: Let me explain. Trial no. 13 in the upper example is incorrect (correct == 0). The following trial (trial no.14) should be labeled as FALSE whereas trial no.13 remains TRUE. Similarly, trial no.19 should be TRUE, whereas trial no.20 should be FALSE. Same with trial no.39 and 40. I hope this is clear now. I tried to do the same in case of missing trials and was able to do it with the help of the following code:  df$use_er <- TRUE
df$use_er[2:nrow(df)] <- df$correct[-nrow(df)]==1 | df$correct[-1]==1
df$use_er[is.na(df$correct)] <- FALSE
df$use_er[2:nrow(df)][is.na(df$correct)] <- FALSE

Comment: I see, so the rule for `use_er` depends _only_ on the preceding trial. Changed that.